# python resample/group by OHLC data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have hourly OHLC data that I am trying to regroup to see only from 9pm to 5am in one row and than for every day like that.
I've tried several ways suggested here, but without success.

```
index_21_09 = eur.index.indexer_between_time('21:00','05:00')
df = eur.iloc[index_21_09]
```

With this I filter data from 21 - 05, but in several rows, I need them in one row.
then, I tried this:

```
df_day_max = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='8h')).max()
df_day_min = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = '8h')).min()
df_group = (pd.concat([df_day_max['High'], df_day_min['Low ']], axis=1).dropna())
```

But, I get data from 16.00 - 00.00! How, if I previously filter them from 21-05?

```
df_resample = df.resample('8H').ohlc()
```

With this, I get same result, only with NaN values.

Any help with this? Thanks.